# jQuery: jqPlot function call won't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, function, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I am basically wondering why this first code works but not the 2nd.

```
<a data-role="button" href="#page2" type="button" onClick="drawChart([[["Test1",6],["Test2",5],["Test3",2]]])">
 <img src="icons/page2.png" inline style="height:80px"/><br/>Tilbakemelding
</a>
```

The above code does NOT work.

Within page2 I made a button with the following code:

```
<div data-role="content">
<a type="button" onClick=drawChart([[["Test1",6],["Test2",5],["Test3",2]]])>Show Chart</a>
</div>
```

This code works, but I would really prefer to have the chart up without having to do that extra click. This is coded in jQueryMobile so the first button does not only load the chart but also navigates to page2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error; your `"`s are all off.  Try:

```
onClick="drawChart([[['Test1',6],['Test2',5],['Test3',2]]])"
```

Comment: Indeed nice spot, but still didn't help. I still have to click the 2nd button to get the chart to show. :/

Comment: @Tom in this case I think there might be something else in your code, please provide a working sample.

Comment: @Tom, have you debugged your javascript with firebug or chrome-devtools?

Comment: Couldn't pick up anything regarding these features, but I found out my simpledialogs are broken though. :p